# Getting No converter found error

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, soap, spring-data-jpa

```
Query(value = "SELECT * FROM test where id = :key", nativeQuery=true)
 public User findById(@Param("key") String key);
```

The above query working is fine.

```
Query(value = "SELECT * FROM test where id = :key", nativeQuery=true)
  public localhost._8080.ws.User findId(@Param("key") String key);
```

But the above query getting the error as below :

> No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [localhost._8080.ws.User]

SOAP XSD created auto generated classes and expecting output localhost._8080.ws.User type due to that getting error.

Please suggest on this error.

Comment: I think your  "User" class  and "localhost._8080.ws.User" both are not same.

Comment: @gajju_15, Yes soap created one more class based on xsd.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA is not intended to map arbitrary results of SQL statements to arbitrary objects.

It maps results into DTOs or projections. 
Most likely you generated class has properties it doesn't know how to handle.

Probably the most sensible way to solve this is to have the repository return something it can handle (`User` or a `Map` should work) and create your desired type from there using your own code or a library intended for such conversion.
[Dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer) seems a popular choice for that.